# Visual Studio 2015 How to run a .wsf with a button. Possible?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2015, windows-scripting

Okay I have been trying to figure this out if anyone can help me I would be more then grateful.

The code is below im having an issue where it does not **execute** the **.wsf**

**1.** Does anyone see anything that im **missing?**

**2.** Am I approaching this correctly?

**3.**The script is opening **cmd.exe** and connecting to **telnet** and running commands.

```
namespace CamSwitch_V1._3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"cscript //B //Nologo c:\scripts\Cam1.wsf");

        }
    }
}
```

Let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: you running a .vbs not a .wsf ?

Comment: I meant to change that back I was trying both with no luck. I would rather use the .wsf I will edit the code.